# SQL Query to retrieve all columns from all parent/childs tables in DB giving a specific Key

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, iteration

So, I will try to explain my issue.
I have a DB with several tables sharing a same ID, what I would need is a general Query that gives me something like a inner join 'row' with all information available from all tables present in my DB that have that specific Key (ID).
I believe it would be something using CTE...or maybe not...

Hope you can help, thanks ;)

Edit:
I will try to be more precise.
Let say we have the following tables:

> Table A {ID: 1, 2, 3; Name: Sean, Roger, Pierce}
>
> Table B {ID: 1, 2, 3; Surname : Connery, Moore, Brosnan}
>
> Table C {ID: 1, 2, 3; Year: 1970, 1980, 1990}
>
> Table Z {ID: 1, 2, 3; Movie: Thunderball, Moonraker, GoldenEye}

The idea would be giving ID=2

> Result: {ID:2; Name: Roger; Surname: Moore; Year:1980;...; Movie: Moonraker}

And this with has many tables we have in the DB.

Thanks and sorry for the indentation!

Comment: This is way too vague to answer specifically. Try to improve your question please

Comment: are you looking to identify columns from your database tables or actual row level information

Comment: I will try to be more precise.
Let say we have the following tables:
 
Table A         Table B         Table C      .... Table Z ... etc
ID  Name        ID  Surname     ID   Year         ID Movie
 1  Roger        1  Moore        1   1980          1 Moonraker
 2  Sean         2  Connery      2   1970          2 Thunderball
 3  Pierce       3  Brosnan      3   1990          3 GoldenEye

The idea would be giving ID=2 
Result:
ID  Name   Surname  Year   ...  Movie
 1  Roger  Moore    1980   ...  Moonraker

And this with has many tables we have in the DB.
Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that from those three tables you want all pertinent information where the ID is the same? For example, if you want all info with an ID of 3 you should have Pierce, Brosnan, 1990, Goldeneye returned (your example is wrong by the way).

Comment: @Ryan :Yes, exactly :)

Comment: Are you saying you don't know what tables there might be, and you want to dynamically join them all?  Or do you know the set of tables?  Because the latter is easy.

Comment: @pmbAustin Right I don't know, that is why it is not so easy, unfortunately. Yes, dynamically that would be the idea...

Comment: So the next question:  Are there Foreign Key Constraints that link all the ID columns in all the tables back to a master table (for referential integrity) or are you going to be going solely based on the column name & type to determine whether to join two tables?

Comment: @pmbAustin Unfortunately the two cases would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is, given one value in one column in one table, is to find all the rows which reference that value in all tables, **you need to go to the DB metadata**.

In DB2 for example you want views in the SYSCAT schema. From that metadata you can find foreign keys and start building dynamic sql to get the rows you want.

From my experience **looking up DB metadata is a code smell**. Perhaps you need to check that your schema is normalized and supports accessing the data in useful ways.

Comment: Ok, I will have a look, but does not seem easy for a SQL beginner ;)